# Generate Secure Token - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a process flow where I send a user a link via email with a generated token.

I'm currently generating the token like this:

```
before_create :generate_token

protected

def generate_token
  self.token = loop do
    random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
    break random_token unless ModelName.exists?(token: random_token)
  end
end
```

The user can access the record by going to

```
mysite.com/records/:token
```

How can I accomplish the same task with either a hashed or encrypted token? I want to make this link more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html).

> MessageVerifier makes it easy to generate and verify messages which
>   are signed to prevent tampering.

[How Does MessageVerifier Work?](http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/reading_rails_how_does_message_verifier_work)